# Como setar valores únicos aceitáveis para uma propriedade Enum em uma classe Serializable?

Tags: c#, .net, validação, serialização, atributos

Dado uma `enum` como exemplo:

```
public enum IcmsCst
{
    [XmlEnum("00")] Cst00,
    [XmlEnum("10")] Cst10,
    [XmlEnum("20")] Cst20,
    ...
}
```

Existe uma forma de anotação para que eu pudesse especificar que um determinado tipo de ICMS poderia aceitar somente um determinado tipo de `CST` desse `Enum`?

Como por exemplo:

```
public class Imposto
{
    [XmlEnum(AcceptOnly = [IcmsCst.Cst00])] // como exemplo do que busco para a limitação
    public ICMS Icms00 { get; set; }
}
```

E com isso essa ter a validação feita automaticamente ao serializar o objeto `Imposto` em um XML?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não tem mecanismo específico pronto. É possível criar um *framework* completo para tratar isso. Ou fazer o simples e na hora de importar a informação tratar se ela é válida ou não. Mecanismos genéricos são úteis para serem reaproveitados. Então existem quando é algo que todo mundo precisa, ou você deve fazer o seu, se precisar usar muitas vezes e isto traz vantagens.

Mesmo se fizer, precisa ter uma forma muito bem pensada de como tratar isso, o que pode não existir uma forma universal. Não aceita, e daí? Nem esse ponto está definido na pergunta, sem o critério claro não tem boa solução. De qualquer forma é muito difícil estabelecer esses critérios em código de forma declarativa.